# Why doesn't my SUMIF formula work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a timetracker sheet that I use at work.  I want to calculate how much time I've spent on each task category.  For some reason it's not working.  As seen below, they're all 0's.

```
=SUMIF(tblTrack[Category],[@Category],tblTrack[Time Spent])
```

[image]

The data in column E (`@Time Spent`) is calculated using the formula `=IF(D4<>"",TEXT(D4-C4,"h:mm"),"")` which I suspect is the problem.  In the sample range below, the data is formatted as `Time` and looks like `1:30 AM` in the formula bar whereas the value in the actual table is just `1:30`.  I suspect this difference is the problem.  How can I modify the formula to output data that can be used with `SUMIF`?

Here is the sample range that works

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your categories are 100% identical between your two tables? For example, in the main screen shot, what do you get from this formula? `=if(G6=A4,"Same","Different")`

Comment: My bet is that you have some look-alike or non-printing characters somewhere.

Comment: @Dane: I get "Same"

Comment: Does a PivotTable give you correct results?

Comment: Also, what is stored in `E4`? Formula? Number? String?

Comment: Dane I think that's the problem.  So the table it works on, the values in the formula bar actually say `1:03:00 AM`. The values in the table are calculated using this formula: `=IF(D4<>"",TEXT(D4-C4,"h:mm"),"")`

Comment: How can I modify the formula to output something that will work with `SUMIF`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you identified, your [Time Spent] column is returning a string. `TEXT()` produces a string from a number, and you can't sum a string.

If you're really avoiding making any changes to the table, the following should work:
`=SUMIF(tblTrack[Category],[@Category],tblTrack[Time Ended])-SUMIF(tblTrack[Category],[@Category],tblTrack[Time Started])`

If you're willing to add a column or replace your current [Time Spent] column, simply enter the `=D4-C4` formula and reference that instead. You can then format the cells to get the "0:30" style, rather than using `=TEXT()`.

Comment: I modified the formula.  It actually still appears in the #:## format.